# DefaultEdge returning null for source and target for jgrapht

Tags: jgrapht

I am iterating over a set of edges returned from a jgrapht directed simple graph.

```
 Set<DefaultEdge> edges = graph.edgeSet();

    for (DefaultEdge edge : edges) {

       System.out.println(edge.getSource());
       System.out.println(edge.getTarget());

}
```

the `edgeSet` method returns the correct amount of edges, but the source and target are always null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I instantiated my graph and passed it an edge class:

```
DirectedGraph graph = new SimpleDirectedGraph(DefaultEdge.class);
```

Netbeans gave me the option for what **DefaultEdge.class** file to import, I chose the wrong one. I used the **org.jgraph** library instead of the **org.jgrapht**.

If you are using the DefaultEdge class make sure you are using the one from jgrapht.

```
import org.jgrapht.graph.DefaultEdge;
```

otherwise there will be no compiler error, and everything will seem to work properly until there is an attempt to retrieve the edge data.

Comment: Spent 2 hours struggling with the same problem. Saved my day ! :D